# Spring boot kafka with schema registry - payload is not matching at consumer end

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I have a producer with this configuration

```
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  cloud:
    stream:
      binder:
        consumer-properties:
          key.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
          value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
          schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
          properties:
            specific.avro.reader: true
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: http://localhost:8081
      bindings:
        event-in-0:
          destination: event-details
          contentType: application/*+avro
          group: group1
      function:
        definition: event
```

This is my schema

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Event",
  "namespace": "com.example.schema.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "eventId",
      "type": "int"
    }
  ]
}
```

and code to publish the message

```
public void sendEvent(final EventDto eventDto) {
    final Event apply = event().apply(eventDto);
    final Message<Event> build = MessageBuilder.withPayload(apply)
            .setHeader("partitionKey", eventDto.eventId())
            .setHeader("customHeader", "test").build();
    final boolean send = streamBridge.send("event-out-0", build);
    log.info(String.valueOf(build));
}
```

This produces the correct event as seen in the logs

```
2022-08-15 09:12:23.988  INFO 25112 --- [nio-9090-exec-5] c.e.eventproducer.service.EventService   : GenericMessage [payload={"eventId": 200}, headers={customHeader=test, id=70c3e52c-f419-cf0c-8fae-0ba07d8876da, partitionKey=200, timestamp=1660547543987}]
```

Now at the consumer end, I expect the same eventId:200 but I always get 0 no matter what the event id is. This is my consumer configuration

```
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  cloud:
    stream:
      binder:
        consumer-properties:
          key.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
          value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
          schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
          properties:
            specific.avro.reader: true
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: http://localhost:8081
      bindings:
        event-in-0:
          destination: event-details
          contentType: application/*+avro
          group: group1
      function:
        definition: event
```

This is to subscribe the message

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<Event>> event() {
    return e -> {
        log.info(e.toString());
        eventRepository.save(new com.example.eventconsumer.doamin.Event(e.getPayload().getEventId()));
    };
}
```

and the log shows

```
2022-08-15 09:12:23.992  INFO [,b19cd949219432acf232403bdcea45c2,1464ff27cfed8011] 24596 --- [container-0-C-1] c.e.eventconsumer.service.EventService   : GenericMessage [payload={"eventId": 0}, headers={customHeader=test, deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, scst_partition=0, kafka_receivedTopic=event-details, kafka_offset=97, partitionKey=200, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@41d9d95, source-type=kafka, id=0762521f-069b-a91d-acc5-69e6bb2eb4eb, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/vnd.event.v1+avro, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1660547543987, kafka_groupId=group1, timestamp=1660547543992}]
```

Here is the auto-generated Event.java class from .avsc file

```
    /**
 * Autogenerated by Avro
 *
 * DO NOT EDIT DIRECTLY
 */
package com.example.schema.avro;

import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData;
import org.apache.avro.message.BinaryMessageEncoder;
import org.apache.avro.message.BinaryMessageDecoder;
import org.apache.avro.message.SchemaStore;

@SuppressWarnings("all")
@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public class Event extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4520271777387293905L;
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Event\",\"namespace\":\"com.example.schema.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"eventId\",\"type\":\"int\"}]}");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }

  private static SpecificData MODEL$ = new SpecificData();

  private static final BinaryMessageEncoder<Event> ENCODER =
      new BinaryMessageEncoder<Event>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);

  private static final BinaryMessageDecoder<Event> DECODER =
      new BinaryMessageDecoder<Event>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);

  /**
   * Return the BinaryMessageDecoder instance used by this class.
   */
  public static BinaryMessageDecoder<Event> getDecoder() {
    return DECODER;
  }

  /**
   * Create a new BinaryMessageDecoder instance for this class that uses the specified {@link SchemaStore}.
   * @param resolver a {@link SchemaStore} used to find schemas by fingerprint
   */
  public static BinaryMessageDecoder<Event> createDecoder(SchemaStore resolver) {
    return new BinaryMessageDecoder<Event>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$, resolver);
  }

  /** Serializes this Event to a ByteBuffer. */
  public java.nio.ByteBuffer toByteBuffer() throws java.io.IOException {
    return ENCODER.encode(this);
  }

  /** Deserializes a Event from a ByteBuffer. */
  public static Event fromByteBuffer(
      java.nio.ByteBuffer b) throws java.io.IOException {
    return DECODER.decode(b);
  }

  @Deprecated public int eventId;

  /**
   * Default constructor.  Note that this does not initialize fields
   * to their default values from the schema.  If that is desired then
   * one should use <code>newBuilder()</code>.
   */
  public Event() {}

  /**
   * All-args constructor.
   * @param eventId The new value for eventId
   */
  public Event(java.lang.Integer eventId) {
    this.eventId = eventId;
  }

  public org.apache.avro.Schema getSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }
  // Used by DatumWriter.  Applications should not call.
  public java.lang.Object get(int field$) {
    switch (field$) {
    case 0: return eventId;
    default: throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException("Bad index");
    }
  }

  // Used by DatumReader.  Applications should not call.
  @SuppressWarnings(value="unchecked")
  public void put(int field$, java.lang.Object value$) {
    switch (field$) {
    case 0: eventId = (java.lang.Integer)value$; break;
    default: throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException("Bad index");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the 'eventId' field.
   * @return The value of the 'eventId' field.
   */
  public java.lang.Integer getEventId() {
    return eventId;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the value of the 'eventId' field.
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setEventId(java.lang.Integer value) {
    this.eventId = value;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new Event RecordBuilder.
   * @return A new Event RecordBuilder
   */
  public static com.example.schema.avro.Event.Builder newBuilder() {
    return new com.example.schema.avro.Event.Builder();
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new Event RecordBuilder by copying an existing Builder.
   * @param other The existing builder to copy.
   * @return A new Event RecordBuilder
   */
  public static com.example.schema.avro.Event.Builder newBuilder(com.example.schema.avro.Event.Builder other) {
    return new com.example.schema.avro.Event.Builder(other);
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new Event RecordBuilder by copying an existing Event instance.
   * @param other The existing instance to copy.
   * @return A new Event RecordBuilder
   */
  public static com.example.schema.avro.Event.Builder newBuilder(com.example.schema.avro.Event other) {
    return new com.example.schema.avro.Event.Builder(other);
  }

  /**
   * RecordBuilder for Event instances.
   */
  public static class Builder extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBuilderBase<Event>
    implements org.apache.avro.data.RecordBuilder<Event> {

    private int eventId;

    /** Creates a new Builder */
    private Builder() {
      super(SCHEMA$);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Builder by copying an existing Builder.
     * @param other The existing Builder to copy.
     */
    private Builder(com.example.schema.avro.Event.Builder other) {
      super(other);
      if (isValidValue(fields()[0], other.eventId)) {
        this.eventId = data().deepCopy(fields()[0].schema(), other.eventId);
        fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Builder by copying an existing Event instance
     * @param other The existing instance to copy.
     */
    private Builder(com.example.schema.avro.Event other) {
            super(SCHEMA$);
      if (isValidValue(fields()[0], other.eventId)) {
        this.eventId = data().deepCopy(fields()[0].schema(), other.eventId);
        fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      }
    }

    /**
      * Gets the value of the 'eventId' field.
      * @return The value.
      */
    public java.lang.Integer getEventId() {
      return eventId;
    }

    /**
      * Sets the value of the 'eventId' field.
      * @param value The value of 'eventId'.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.example.schema.avro.Event.Builder setEventId(int value) {
      validate(fields()[0], value);
      this.eventId = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Checks whether the 'eventId' field has been set.
      * @return True if the 'eventId' field has been set, false otherwise.
      */
    public boolean hasEventId() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[0];
    }


    /**
      * Clears the value of the 'eventId' field.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.example.schema.avro.Event.Builder clearEventId() {
      fieldSetFlags()[0] = false;
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Event build() {
      try {
        Event record = new Event();
        record.eventId = fieldSetFlags()[0] ? this.eventId : (java.lang.Integer) defaultValue(fields()[0]);
        return record;
      } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static final org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter<Event>
    WRITER$ = (org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter<Event>)MODEL$.createDatumWriter(SCHEMA$);

  @Override public void writeExternal(java.io.ObjectOutput out)
    throws java.io.IOException {
    WRITER$.write(this, SpecificData.getEncoder(out));
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static final org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader<Event>
    READER$ = (org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader<Event>)MODEL$.createDatumReader(SCHEMA$);

  @Override public void readExternal(java.io.ObjectInput in)
    throws java.io.IOException {
    READER$.read(this, SpecificData.getDecoder(in));
  }

}
```

Interestingly if I pass the partition key as event id then I fetch it correctly but not the payload itself.

Comment: The `id` field in your logs are not the same. Should it be? Also consumer logs seem to be printing `GenericMessage`, not `Event` `toString` message ... Think you want `e.getPayload().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the issue is with your DTO, where the value of the evenId is not setting/getting correctly and it is always returning the default value of int, which is **0**.

This is how it looks the auto-generated class out of your .avsc. So, we need to set/get eventId in your event class appropriately.

```
/** Gets the value of the 'eventId' field */
public java.lang.Integer getEventId() {
  return eventId;
}

/** Sets the value of the 'eventId' field */
public com.example.schema.avro.Event.Builder setEventId(int value) {
  validate(fields()[0], value);
  this.eventId = value;
  fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
  return this; 
}

public Event build() {
  try {
    Event record = new Event();
    record.eventId = fieldSetFlags()[0] ? this.eventId : (java.lang.Integer) defaultValue(fields()[0]);
    return record;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added the auto-generated class which seems to have getter and setter for eventId.